counting prime factors for formatted output
I have a simple code to print the prime factors, but I want to count the numbers for each of the primes and format the output as follows: org_int = p1^e1 * p2 ^ e2...
I'm having issue counting the primes when they occur, where 121 = 11^2
42 = 2^1 * 3^1 * 7^1 is what im going for. I know the count in the current place makes no sense, but im trying to get something down.
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


int main () {
  int integer ;
  cout << "enter integer: ";
  cin >>  integer;

  for (int n = 2; n < integer ; n +=1){
    while (integer % n == 0) {
      count = 0;
      integer = integer / n;
      count = count + 1;
      cout << n^count << endl;
    }
  }
  if (integer != 1) {
  cout << integer << endl;
  }
}


Your basically asking an "algorithm" question not a "C++" one. You will first need to make a collection (std::vector/std::array) of known prime factors and use them
: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. Also you need a way to remember your prime factors + counts (e.g. use a std::map). But how exactly that's for you to find out (it is your homework)

It is nicer to make it so that "^1" is a special case to aid readability. Move cout <<... outside the inner loop and change it to cout << n << "^" << count  and you will be a lot closer. See other threads on finding primes to avoid wasted effort.

You reinitialize count inside the loop, so it can only be 1 or 0
Using subfunction, and reworking a little the display might give:
void print_primes_factor(std::size_t n)
{
    const char* sep = "";
    for (std::size_t i = 2; i < n ; ++i){
        std::size_t count = 0;
        while (n % i == 0) {
            n = n / i;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count != 0) {
            std::cout << sep << i;
            if (count != 1) {
                std::cout << "^" << count;
            }
            sep = " * ";
        }
    }
    if (n != 1) {
        std::cout << sep << n;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

Demo
